# simple strcat implementation with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, strcat

so I was practicing writing c code with pointers using the K&R. For one problem with *strcat* function, I couldn't find out what was wrong with my code, which according to Visual Studio, returned the destination string unchanged after the strcat function. Any suggestion is appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int strcat(char* s, char* t);
int main(void)
{
char *s="hello ", *t="world";
strcat(s,t);
printf("%s",s);
return 0;
}

int strcat(char* s,char* t)
{
int i;
i=strlen(s)+strlen(t);
s=(char*) malloc(i);
while(*s!='\0')
    s++;
while('\0'!=(*s++=*t++))
    ;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You re-allocate the string `s` inside the function `strcat`, loosing the orignal content.

Comment: `char *strcat(char *d, char const *s) { strcpy(d + strlen(d), s); return d; }`

Answer (score 1):

1) defining string in this way

```
char *s="hello "
```

means that you are defined a literal string. a literal string is saved into read only memory so you can not edit it

you have to define your string as a char array in order to be able to edit it

```
char s[100] = "hello ";
```

2) when you define your function in this way

```
int strcat(char* s,char* t)
```

you can not change the address of `s` into the function `strcat()`. So assigning memory with `malloc()` into the function will not change the `s` address when leaving the function

3) change your function strcat to

```
int strcat(char** s,char* t)
{
    int i;
    char *u, *v;
    i=strlen(*s)+strlen(t);
    v = *s;
    u=(char*) malloc(i+1);
    while(*v!='\0')
        *u++ = *v++;
    while('\0'!=(*u++=*t++));
    *s = u;
    return 0;
}
```

and you call it in the main with:

```
char *s="hello ", *t="world";
strcat(&s,t);
```

Comment: Isn't he making a copy of the pointer when he calls the function? and then does `s=(char*) malloc(i);`

Comment: @Mohamad Had edited ur answer. With *s = u; you are copying '\0' to *s; save the u to some char *f after malloc and and u can iterate u to end of string. and do *s = f;

Answer (score 1):

In

```
 strcat(char* s, char* t)
```

the 's' is send by value. The value of 's' at call time is copied into the stack then strcat() is call. At the return of strcat the modified version is discard from the stack. So the calling value of 's' is never changed (and you create a memory leak).

Beward, in C every memory cell can be change, even parameters or instructions sections; some changes can be very hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm pretty sure that `strcat` returns a `char*` in the real implementation (holding the original value of the first string).
2. `strcat` is not supposed to alter the first parameter's address, so you shouldn't call `malloc`.
3. Point #2 means that you need to declare `char *s` as `char s[20]` in `main` (where `20` is some arbitrary number big enough to hold the whole string).

If you really want to alter the value of the an input parameter you will need to pass the address of the value - so it would need to be `strcat(char **s, ...)` in the function declaration/definition, and called with `strcat(&s, ...)` in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to do like the real strcat it's said that the first parameter

> ```
> The string s1 must have sufficient space to hold the result.
> ```

so you don't need to use malloc

```
char *strcat(char* s, const char* t);
int main(void)
{
  char s[15] = {0}; // 
  char *t = "world";  //const char * so you can't change it

  strcpy(s, "Hello ");
  strcat(s,t);
  printf("%s\n",s);
  return (0);
}

char *strcat(char* s, const char* t)
{
  int i = 0;

  while (s[i] != '\0')
    i++;
  while (*t != '\0')
    s[i++] = *t++;
  s[i] = '\0'; //useless because already initialized with 0
  return (s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define LIMIT 100
void strcatt(char*,char*);
main()
{   
int i=0;
char s[LIMIT];
char t[LIMIT];
strcpy(s,"hello");
strcpy(t,"world");
strcatt(s,t);
printf("%s",s);
getch();
}
void strcatt(char *s,char *t)
{   

while(*s!='\0')
{    
 s++;
}
*s=' ';
++s;
while(*t!='\0')
{
    *s=*t;
    s++;
    t++;
}
*s=*t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Dear user*,

you don't have to complicate things that much. The simpliest code for `strcat`, using pointers:

```
void strcat(char *s, char *t) {
    while(*s++); /*This will point after the '\0' */
    --s; /*So we decrement the pointer to point to '\0' */
    while(*s++ = *t++); /*This will copy the '\0' from *t also */
}
```

Although, this won't give you report about the concatenation's success.

Look at this `main()` part for the rest of the answer:

```
int main() {
    char s[60] = "Hello ";
    char *t  = "world!";

    strcat(s, t);
    printf("%s\n", s);

    return 0;
}
```

The `s[60]` part is very important, because you can't concatenate an another string to it's end if it doesn't have enough space for that.